# lstnewenvironment/lstset : using colors conditionally emph/emphstyle - SAS: (in=_x) versus if x in (1,2)

Tags: listings

I'm using `lstnewenvironment` to color my SAS datasteps. I'm using emph/emphstyle to add new keywords (as I didn't get to work morekeyword and otherkeyword).

If I use (`in=...`) after a dataset name the in should be considered as a keyword (in blue)

If I use x in (1,2) then in should not be considered as a keyword.

How can I conditionally assign a color to in when it is followed by an equal sign (or blank + equal sign) and black when it isn't ?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Right now the only solution I got is to use `escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}`, and assign manually the color locally.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}

    \definecolor{sasdarkblue}   {RGB}{0,0,114}      %#000072
    \definecolor{sasblue}       {RGB}{21,23,206}    %#1517CE
    \definecolor{sasviolet}     {RGB}{109,23,110}   %#6D176E

\lstnewenvironment{sasdatastep}{%
\lstset{%
    basicstyle      =\small\ttfamily,%
    language        =SAS,%
    keywordstyle    =\color{sasblue}\ttfamily,%
    escapechar      =|,%
    escapeinside    ={(*@}{@*)},%
    stringstyle     =\color{sasviolet}\ttfamily,%
    showstringspaces=false,%
    keepspaces      =true,%
    sensitive       =false,%
    emph            =[1]{run,data,\%macro,\%mend}, %
    emphstyle       =[1]\color{sasdarkblue}\ttfamily\textbf, %
    emph            =[2]{in,indsname,point,nobs},%
    emphstyle       =[2]\color{sasblue}, %
emph            =[3]{indsname,point,nobs},%
    upquote         =true%
}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{sasdatastep}
data new;
    set one (in=_one)
        two (in=_two);
run;

data one;
   set one (where=(x in (1,2)));
run;
\end{sasdatastep}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please post a minimal but complete example that others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier and faster for others to help.

Comment: (2) I've now added an example in the question.

Comment: I don't think that is possible in listings, you'll probably need to use external tools like `minted`.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to use this kind of conditionals with `listings`. To put it simply, `listings` only reads from left to right (sort of), so when it matches and highlights an `in`, it doesn't know yet whether a `=` follows it or not.

It seems that the setting `keywordsprefix={in=}` does the trick in your example, but it has severe limitations:

- According to the documentation, `keywordsprefix` is still buggy. I'm not even sure it's *supposed* to work in this situation.
- You can only use one `keywordsprefix` at a time, so you can't match both `in =` and `in=` (with and without space).

---

The following is a hack which consists in matching all occurences of `in=` and `in =`, hiding them, and reinserting them with the correct highlighting. There might be cleaner ways to do this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}

    \definecolor{sasdarkblue}   {RGB}{0,0,114}      %#000072
    \definecolor{sasblue}       {RGB}{21,23,206}    %#1517CE
    \definecolor{sasviolet}     {RGB}{109,23,110}   %#6D176E

\newcommand{\highlightIn}{%
    \textcolor{sasblue}{in}=%
}
\newcommand{\highlightInWithSpace}{%
    \textcolor{sasblue}{in} =%
}

\lstnewenvironment{sasdatastep}{%
\lstset{%
    basicstyle      =\small\ttfamily,%
    language        =SAS,%
    keywordstyle    =\color{sasblue}\ttfamily,%
    escapechar      =|,%
    escapeinside    ={(*@}{@*)},%
    stringstyle     =\color{sasviolet}\ttfamily,%
    showstringspaces=false,%
    keepspaces      =true,%
    sensitive       =false,%
    emph            =[1]{run,data,\%macro,\%mend}, %
    emphstyle       =[1]\color{sasdarkblue}\ttfamily\textbf, %
    emph            =[2]{indsname,point,nobs},%
    emphstyle       =[2]\color{sasblue}, %
emph            =[3]{indsname,point,nobs},%
    upquote         =true,%
    moredelim=**[il][\highlightIn]{in=}, % `**` is needed so that `in=` is only reinserted once
    moredelim=**[il][\highlightInWithSpace]{in\ =},
    columns=flexible % the replaced text wouldn't fit correctly with fixed columns
}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{sasdatastep}
data new;
    set one (in=_one)
        two (in=_two);
run;

data one;
   set one (where=(x in (1,2)));
run;
\end{sasdatastep}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: highlighted code]

---

To expand on daleif's comment, other tools such as [`minted`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) might be better suited for this. However, in this case, `minted`/`Pygments` doesn't take into account the different uses of `in`, it highlights it every time. One would need a whole new lexer to solve your issue with `minted`.